# How to customized and Override Parameter Values from POJO?

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I am working on Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE and Open API Integration example. This example has capability to search using 20 different parameters. So this POJO class holds `CustomSearchDto` these 20 different values.

In the POJO I used orgName, but `@parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "orgizationName",` and somehow I wanted to override the variable name. I must do that. Is there any way to do it ?

```
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "orgizationName", schema = @Schema(type = "string")) 
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "employeeId", schema = @Schema(type = "string")) 
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "emailId", schema = @Schema(type = "string")) 
@Parameter(in=ParameterIn.QUERY, name="page", description="Results page you want to retrieve (0..N)", schema=@Schema(defaultValue = "0"))
    @Parameter(in=ParameterIn.QUERY, name="size", description="Number of records per page.", schema=@Schema(defaultValue = "30"))
@GetMapping(value = "/employees/organizations")
public ResponseEntity<PagedModel<Employees>> search(CustomSearchDto requestparams,
        @Parameter(hidden=true) Pageable pageRequest) {

    ......
    ........

    return new ResponseEntity<>(model, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here is my custom DTO class

```
public class CustomSearchDto {
    @Schema(description = "", type = "string", example = " ")
    private String orgName;

    @Schema(description = "", type = "string", example = " ")
    private String empId;

    @Schema(description = "", type = "integer", example = "null")
    private Integer email;

    .........
    ..............
    .............
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass directly you object CustomSearchDto with the annotation `@ParameterObject`.

Here is the link for the documentation:

- https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-extract-fields-from-parameter-object-